# CLIPs How can I print all defacts as result throught a Defrule? Or be able to insert multiple traits as answer?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, clips, expert-system

I'm working on a project that let's users find a list of jasmines based on flower color and blooming seasons, but I haven't found an effective way to be able to print all jasmines currently on the program at once by using a defrule

```
    (deftemplate jazmin 
    (slot nombre) 
    (slot color-flor
        (allowed-values blanca amarilla)) 
    (multislot floracion
        (allowed-values invierno primavera verano otono)) 
)

(defrule in-color-flor
    =>
    (printout t "Inserte el color de la flor: ")
    (assert (color-flor (read)))
)

(defrule in-floracion
    =>
    (printout t "Inserte en que mes florece: ")
    (assert (floracion (read)))
)

(defrule buscar-jazmin
    (color-flor ?color-flor)
    (floracion ?floracion)
    (jazmin (nombre ?nombre) (color-flor ?color-flor) (floracion $? ?floracion $?))
    =>
    (printout t "El nombre del jazmin descrito es: " ?nombre crlf)
)

(defrule jazmin-no-encontrado
    (color-flor ?color-flor)
    (floracion ?floracion)
    (not (jazmin (nombre ?nombre) (color-flor ?color-flor) (floracion $? ?floracion $?)))
    =>
    (printout t "El jazmin descrito no se encuentra" crlf)
)

(deffacts jazmines
    (jazmin (nombre Jazmin-Blanco) (color-flor blanca) (floracion primavera verano otono))
    (jazmin (nombre Jazmin-Chino) (color-flor blanca) (floracion primavera))
    (jazmin (nombre Jazmin-Silvestre) (color-flor amarilla) (floracion verano))
    (jazmin (nombre Jazmin-Azor) (color-flor blanca) (floracion primavera))
    (jazmin (nombre Jazmin-Espanol) (color-flor blanca) (floracion verano otono))
    (jazmin (nombre Jazmin-Amarillo) (color-flor amarilla) (floracion invierno primavera))
)
```

I want to know if it's possible to print all of them in one rule, or be able to specify more than one trait in a single (run).

Answer (score 0):

A rule that prints all of them is:

```
(defrule jazmin
    (jazmin (nombre ?nombre))
    =>
    (printout t "jazmin " ?nombre crlf)
)
```

Your rules already allow you to specify more than one trait (color and floracion).